# How to show that $S_n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_n(\Bbb F_p)$ where $\Bbb F_p$ is a field with $p$ prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to show that $S_n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_n(\Bbb F_p)$ where $\Bbb F_p$ is a field with $p$ prime, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers. Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: have you considered [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix)?

Comment: How is your question about $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ related to your title?

Comment: The group order is exactly what I put in the title.

Comment: Where does $(p^n-1)(p^n-p)\cdot\ldots\cdot(p^n-p^{n-1})$ come into the picture?

Comment: I am not an American so you may have difficulty understanding and you say in English if a question was where I got the problem from, to the teacher who gave me my test.

Comment: This is true, and the proof is the same, for any field $K$, not just for a finite field of order $p$.

Answer (score 2):

First, let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{F}_p^n$, and denote the identity matrix $I\in GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ as $[e_1~\dots~e_n]$. Now, consider the map

$$\varphi:S_n\to GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)\text{ such that }\pi\mapsto [e_{\pi(1)}~\dots~e_{\pi(n)}].$$

I claim that $\varphi$ is injective. To show this, I only need to show that if $\pi\mapsto I$, then $\pi$ is the identity element of $S_n$. Indeed, if $\pi\mapsto I$, then $\pi(i)=i$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, so $\pi$ must be the identity, proving that $\varphi$ is injective.

Therefore, we know that $S_n\cong\varphi(S_n)$ by the isomorphism theorem on groups. Since $\varphi(S_n)<GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$, this implies that $S_n$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$.